# Local Storage Error in Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio-2012, azure-storage

I'm having a problem when I start the Azure Storage Emulator:

[image]

I have tried to do the tips in the url informed into the window, but nothing is working. Anyone can help?

Comment: This problem bothered me for 3 months!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the following:

```
C:\> SqlLocalDb i
v11.0
C:\> SqlLocalDb stop   "v11.0"
C:\> SqlLocalDb delete "v11.0"
```

References: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/

Answer (score 0):

when I faced this problem I just solved it by going to the location where the previous storage emulator database was created, and then I deleted it.  After that it worked perfectly with me.

Let me know if that works for you too.